# Debugging process for Kafka SSL security

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I was able to set up the SSL in my Kafka brokers and client and I am also able to see that when we produce messages using the 9093 port that is the SSL port the messages are consumed by the consumer.

I tried to send a message via the 9093 port and the message is sent to the consumer from the producer.

Is there any way to verify if this is actually working, I mean how can I demonstrate that 9092 is not SSL and 9093 is SSL and secured?

Comment: You must be configured SSL with some key and password. If your SSL port is running 9093 and you are only able to consume by  providing that key and password then your SSL is working well otherwise something wrong with your SSL set up.

Answer (score 10):

Below two ways can verify the setup of SSL.

1. `-Djavax.net.debug=all`  Add this property in 
   `bin/kafka-run-class.sh` at the same place as:

   ```
   if [ -z "$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS" ]; then
       KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="  <**add here**>  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "
   fi
   ```

   then tail the kafka broker log file, you should see some encoded messages.
2. To verify if the server's keystore and truststore are setup correctly you can run the following command:

   ```
   openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1
   ```

   Note: TLSv1 should be listed under ssl.enabled.protocols.

   In the output of this command you should see the server’s certificate:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   {variable sized random bytes}
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   subject=/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Clara/O=org/OU=org/CN=Joe Smith
   issuer=/C=US/ST=CA/L=Santa Clara/O=org/OU=org/CN=kafka/emailAddress=test@test.com
   ```

   If the certificate does not show up or if there are any other error messages then your keystore is not setup correctly.

Reference :

1. http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html
2. https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9

Answer (score 0):

We have tried setting up kafka with SSL and faced the same issue to crosscheck if its working on SSL I removed the listeners entry PLAINTEXT and kept the configuration which is required for SSL only and tested. We were able to send and receive message wirh SSL at secure port 9093 .

In logs it does gives a WARNING but it's for the client authentication so that's not an issue , once tested I added the PLAINTEXT entry again .

I know it's not the best way to test but it worked for me

Comment: Yes i have also done the same thing and i am able to send and receive messages on port 9093 but, i was thinking of some other ways maybe via wireshark or something which can be used to see the encryption. Can we?

Answer (score -1):

When you mention security.protocol=SSL, there is no way it can use the other protocol. For more proofs, as mentioned above you can edit the kafka-run-class.sh to turn on debug all and verify the ssl handshakes happening and metadata being sent over ssl channel.

Thanks
Akash

Comment: The question was not about "if" kafka uses SSL if configured so, it was about how to verify it is really doing it.
So, your answer does nor answer the question, neither add anything new in contrast to supermonk's answer, leave a comment for these kind of suggestions instead.
At the very worst, your answer is wrong, as of course, there could always be an implementation flaw anywhere in the code, which leads to Kafka not using SSL even though configured to do so.